# Google Multiple Markers Mapped in Sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I am using the example [Google Maps API V3 for ASP.NET on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET) and it works very well.

I'd like to add a little functionality to it but I'm not sure it is possible. I have done some research but I'm not sure what I the terminology for this is.

We have a lat/lon being reported to our SQL Server every 15 seconds. I'd like to take a reading at every minute and map the route where the vehicle has gone for x number number of readings

I can put pins on the maps with lat/lon without a problem but I'd like to show the route that it went, with lines or something to the like.

Is this possible with Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  In the Google Maps API, these are called `Polyline`s.

Here is a link to the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline

And here is one of the developer samples using `Polyline`s:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex